# Slf4j rolling file appender

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Hi i have an elder version of log4j that i cant seem to get to roll the log files correctly.

the log files are rolled as this... xxx.log --> xxx.log.5 --> xxx.log.4

i want them to roll in the opposite direction so that when xxx.log reaches 200kb it rolls to xxx.log.1 and so forth till it reaches xxx.log.5
after that it should not roll further but delete the oldest file.

i am using a logger.properties file

```
log4j.appender.fil=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fil.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.fil.File=Logs/xxx.log
log4j.appender.fil.MaxFileSize=200kB
log4j.appender.fil.MaxBackupIndex=5
```

here i thought the solution would have been to add the folowing line to make it roll as i wanted
log4j.appender.fil.fileNamePattern=Logs/xxx.log.%i

thanks in advance to anyone who might try and help me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this option does not exist. But you can extend the RollingFileAppender class to fit your needs

Comment: its a RollingFileAppender so it should have the option to set up how it rolls.
i found a lot of options on how to roll on date etc.